# IDisposable Pattern. How does my finalizer's call of dispose ever free managed resources?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, finalizer

I have Class A that implements the Disposable pattern in order to release unmanaged resources such as unsubscribing from events. Class B uses Class A, but does not wrap it in a using {..} block nor explicity calls A.Dispose(true) so A.dispose is called in A's finalizer via the standard Dispose(false) call. But then by setting the bool parameter to false, the unmanaged resources will not be cleaned up, i.e not unsubscribing from subscribed events. Shouldn't the finalizer be calling Dispose(true) or should Class B explicitly call A.Dispose(true) at some point such as in its own finalizer?

```
private bool _disposed = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _promotionsSQLTableDependency.Stop();
                _awardsSQLTableDependency.Stop();
                _progressiveGeneratorService.OnProgressiveLevelsUpdate -= _progressiveUpdateHandler;
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~PromotionHandler()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> implements the Disposable pattern in order to release unmanaged resources such as unsubscribing from events.

Unsubscribing from an event isn't an unmanaged resource that needs to be cleaned up though.

> Class B uses Class A, but does not wrap it in a using {..} block nor explicity calls A.Dispose(true)

You should treat that as a bug in your program.  The whole point of implementing `IDisposable` is because that object needs to be explicitly cleaned up with the owner(s) are finished with it.

> But then by setting the bool parameter to false, the unmanaged resources will not be cleaned up,

But those aren't unmanaged resources, which is why they aren't cleaned up in the finally block.

> Shouldn't the finalizer be calling Dispose(true) or should Class B explicitly call A.Dispose(true) at some point such as in its own finalizer?

No.  You shouldn't be interacting with managed objects in the finalizer.  It's not safe to do so.  Since you have no unmanaged resources to clean up in a finalizer, you shouldn't even *have* a finalizer.

Comment: How is unsubscribing from an event not an unmanaged resource? The GC isn't going to unsubscribe from the event and so the raiser of the event is going to still have a reference to the subscribed object. I also understand now that I should be calling A.dispose somewhere in B's code, but where would that be placed since B uses A for its entire lifetime?

Comment: @EdgarArakelyan You're accessing another managed GC object.  An unmanaged resource would be something like a file hand, memory manually allocated rather than using the GC, resources provided by interopping with C/C++, etc.  "The GC isn't going to unsubscribe from the event and so the raiser of the event is going to still have a reference to the subscribed object."  Yes.  Is the object with the event going to outlive this object for an extended period of time, and does this object contain significant expensive resources that would be problematic to hold onto?  If not, then that's not a problem.

Comment: Yes I do need to unsubscribe from the event in this case as the raiser of the event may outlive the subscriber of the event. So from what I understand I should unsubscribe from events in my if statement as that is a managed resource. But I should call sqltabledependency.stop() outside of the if statement as those are unmanaged resources correct?

Comment: @EdgarArakelyan "but where would that be placed since B uses A for its entire lifetime" If a type is holding a reference to an `IDisposable` object as a field then the type should itself become `IDisposable`, and dispose of the disposable resource it is holding in its own dispose method.  Such an object doesn't need a finalizer.

Comment: @EdgarArakelyan No, those are both managed objects.  Neither of them should be accessed outside of the if.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying it up I learned a good amount with your help.

Comment: As long as your object A still subscribes to OnProgressiveLevelsUpdate event of another object C, the garbage collector will never remove A while C is still alive. The subscription from A to C prevents the GC from collecting A while C is still alive because it means that C has a reference to A. Only if both objects have no more external references, both will be collected. In this case, unsubscribing is obsolete and can even be dangerous because C could have its Finalizer called before A

Comment: @NineBerry from what I understand an Object A should only be unsubscribing from an event from an Object C if Lifetime(C) > Lifetime(A) which I believe is the case for me here.

Comment: @EdgarArakelyan It should be unsubscribing if the lifetime of C is *significantly* greater, not just greater, *and* if A is expensive to keep around, i.e. it is a very large object.

Answer (score 0):

The dispose method must only use the disposing parameter to decide whether to free managed resources. Unmanaged resources must always be freed.

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Free managed resources
        }

        // always free unmanaged resources

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

if the Dispose call happens via the garbage collector (=via a call to the Finalizer) and the disposing is false, you don't need to free the managed resources. The garbage collector will also call the Finalizer of those managed objects (maybe even earlier).

This is what [the documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose):

> In the second overload, the disposing parameter is a Boolean that
>   indicates whether the method call comes from a Dispose method (its
>   value is true) or from a finalizer (its value is false).
>
> The body of the method consists of two blocks of code:
>
> - A block that frees unmanaged resources. This block executes regardless of the value of the disposing parameter.
> - A conditional block that frees managed resources. This block executes if the value of disposing is true. The managed resources that
>     it frees can include:
>
> **Managed objects that implement IDisposable**. The conditional block can be used to call their Dispose implementation. If you have used a
>   safe handle to wrap your unmanaged resource, you should call the
>   SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean) implementation here.
>
> **Managed objects that consume large amounts of memory or consume scarce resources**. Freeing these objects explicitly in the Dispose
>   method releases them faster than if they were reclaimed
>   non-deterministically by the garbage collector.
>
> If the method call comes from a finalizer (that is, if disposing is
>   false), only the code that frees unmanaged resources executes. Because
>   the order in which the garbage collector destroys managed objects
>   during finalization is not defined, calling this Dispose overload with
>   a value of false prevents the finalizer from trying to release managed
>   resources that may have already been reclaimed.

Comment: So I should unsubscribe from events outside of my if statement is basically what you're saying?

Comment: @EdgarArakelyan No, because event subscriptions are managed resources.